# Swift Realm getting stuck on re-adding an Object in a write block

Tags: swift, realm

I'm using Realm, the project is on version 1.0.0.

When I create a list of Realm `Object`s (with data obtained from a web API), then try to save them to the Realm using this utility function in a struct:

```
static func saveRealmObjects(objects: [Object]) {
    defer {
        // Never entered
    }

    for object in objects {
        let realm = try! Realm()

        do {
            try realm.write {
                print("TEST: 1: object: \(object)")
                realm.add(object)
                print("TEST: 2")
            }
        } catch {
            // Never entered
        }
    }
}
```

*(Please don't judge me on the exact structure, I've been toying around seeing if anything will work).*

I can tell from liberal use of print statements (mostly removed above) that the function gets to `TEST: 1` okay, but fails to make it to `TEST: 2`, for the very first `Object` in the list I pass to the function.

I should note this function does work the first time I use it with the data (say after wiping the simulator and launching the app afresh), but then if I recreate the `Object`s and try to save them again it gets stuck.

I assumed Realm would use the private key on the `Object`s and overwrite any if necessary. But it seems to just get stuck.

-

Then - after it's stuck - if I try and get another set of results from Realm (using a different `Realm` object) I get the following error:

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type realm::InvalidTransactionException: Cannot create asynchronous query while in a write transaction`

FYI I'm creating a different `Realm` object using `try! Realm()`

-

For reference, here is the `Object` I'm trying to save:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class MyObject: Object {

    // MARK: Realm Primary Key

    dynamic var id: String = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }


    // MARK: Stored Properties

    dynamic var date: NSDate? = nil

    dynamic var numA = 0

    dynamic var numB = 0
    dynamic var numC = 0

    dynamic var numD = 0
    dynamic var numE = 0

    dynamic var numF = 0
    dynamic var numG = 0

    dynamic var numH = 0


    // MARK: Computed Properties

    var computedNumI: Int {
        return numD + numE
    }

    var computedNumJ: Int {
        return numF + numG
    }

}
```

*(The variable names have been changed.)*

-

Hopefully I'm doing something obviously wrong - this is my first time using Realm after all.

If you have any ideas why it's sticking (perhaps it's a threading issue?), or want more info, please answer or comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Being the clever clogs I am, I've literally just found the answer by reading the documentation:
https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#creating-and-updating-objects-with-primary-keys

The add to Realm line needed to look like this:

`realm.add(object, update: true)`

Where the update flag will update `Object`s already saved with that primary key.

-

Although it would have been nice if it either gave some sort of obvious warning or crash upon trying to add the same object, or didn't cause other queries and writes to Realm to crash.